# how to return blanks if isna or cell is blank instead of na or 0

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am using the following formula and still getting *#N/A*.

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,18,0))+(VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,18,0)=""),"",VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,18,0))
```

What I want is the cell to be blank if it is *N/A* or the source cell is blank.

Answer (score 0):

```
ISNA(VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,18,0))
```

The `ISNA` is only referring to this `VLOOKUP`. So it starts with `If(False+...,"",vlookup` and the `FALSE` returns the `vlookup`, which can be `#N/A`

To get `ISNA` to be blank you need wrap all of the `vlookup`s in `isna`

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,18,0)+(VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,18,0)="")),"",VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,18,0))
```

Comment: i used an example that stated "For instance, this variation returns a blank if the source is blank or if the source contains an #N/A error:
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B1,D:E,2,0))+(VLOOKUP(B1,D:E,2,0)="")
,"",VLOOKUP(B1,D:E,2,0)) But it is not working as advertised. Any ideas how I can fix the formula? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what you mean; I'm just telling you why it's not working.

Comment: Any ideas of how I can correct the formula to return a blank cell if it is either an error or it finds a blank cell?

Comment: =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,19,0))+(VLOOKUP(B:B,'MAPT UPDATE SHEET'!A:AC,19,0)=""),"", i'm not very good with excel but i assume this part of the formula basically says if its n/a then return "", also (+) if the cell is blank (="") then return blank ("",) instead of a zero.

Comment: No your isna doesn't work after the `+` - it's closed with the `))`

Comment: If your problem is solved please click the green checkmark next to the answer that solved it to mark the question as answered

Answer (score 0):

`=IF(COUNTA({source})=0,"",IFERROR({your formula},""))`

It'll actually give blank cell as result for all error output, not only for `#N/A`.